# How to force not sending other request while parsing html file?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a chrome extension that sends `GET` request to a website and start scraping the `.html` file that returned as response. 
While looking at the Network section in the chrome DevTool I saw that the html is sending a lot of useless (for me) request as they are part of the web page logic.
Is there a way to read and parse the html file as is without the creating all those indirect requests?
The initiator to the other request is the line (as chrome suggest):

```
htmlObject.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
```

This is the part of code I'm running which is relevant to this problem:

```
function makeCall(word) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = processResponse(xhr);
    xhr.open("GET", 'https://school.morfix.co.il/' + word, true);
    xhr.send(null);
}
function processResponse(xhr) {
    return function(){
        if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            var htmlObject = document.createElement('div');
            htmlObject.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            var translations = htmlObject.getElementsByClassName("normal_translation_div");
            for (var i=0; i< translations.length; i++){
                var trans = translations[i].innerHTML;
                console.log(trans.replace(/<span class=\"clearOutputLanguageMeaningsString\">; <\/span>/g, ";"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try accessing [xhr.responseXML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseXML) instead of `responseText`. It should give you a document you can perform queries against.

If that does not work, instead of creating a DOM node you can use the [DOM Parser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to parse the response, like so:

```
const parser = new DOMParser()
const parsedDoc = parser.parseFromString(xhr.responseText, 'text/html')

// now you can use the parsedDoc like a regular document
var translations = parsedDoc.getElementsByClassName("...")
```